# Alarmingly low performance with galera cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-administration, percona, galera

My aim is to utilise sufficient cpu resources of both the nodes in my galera cluster so that my end to end stack can support more TPS. Right now, my full stack is constrained by a single mariadb server of 36vcpu and it can go to 10000 TPS.

I want to support nearly 20000 TPS by using 2 nodes of DB in a galera cluster(As 1 can support around 10000 TPS- this was constrained by **CPU**). At this point of time i dont care about split brain and other replication or border line scenarios. I have tested it initially with 2 nodes in galera with an ha proxy load balancer but got very bad results (3500 TPS only).
Am i trying to achieve something which cannot be done by galera? Some viewpoints please.

Any other mechanism through which i can cluster my DB for the application to go beyond the limitation of 10000 TPS on one node?

Comment: I'm no expert on MySQL clustering, but I think because you are aiming for speed and not replication, you should look at a Shared-Nothing cluster architecture for MySQL like NDB, instead of a replication-focused cluster like Galera.

Comment: You cant use Galera with 2 Nodes in a Production system. If one Node Crashs and resync a second Node is used for the resync so your cluster is down !! Its also important to see the load. for a high read load Galera the best. Also to think about Multicast in the Network, so a Node must only send to 1 Address and not to each node. Optimize the my.cnf. and at last use MaxScal instead HaProxy.

Answer (score 2):

Each transaction (in Galera) must, at `COMMIT` time, talk to all other nodes to confirm that the transaction will work everywhere.  Eventually, those nodes must perform the transaction.  Depending on a lot of factors, this effort may or may not be a lot less than the original node's effort.

All forms of replication involve repeating, on the Slave, the 'write' that occurred on the Master.  The trick is to minimize the Slave's effort; but this can only partially be done.

If a standalone server maxes out at 10K transactions, it is unlikely for *any* replication setup to be able to do 20K across 2 nodes.  It *may* be possible to get 20K with 3 or more nodes.

Galera seems to top out at 4-5 nodes.  That is, the synchronization becomes overwhelming, thereby limiting scaling.

Oracle's "InnoDB Cluster" looks promising for possibly going beyond 5 nodes.  It is somewhat available now in 5.7 and 8.0.

NDB Cluster depends on "eventual consistency", which is a very different model than "asynchronous" (regular replication), "semi-sync", or the "sync" of Galera or InnoDB Cluster.  NDB perhaps shines if transactions never conflict with each other, or at least not from *different* nodes.

There have been experiments where than 10K have been achieved.  Try [*this*](https://gigaom.com/2011/12/06/facebook-shares-some-secrets-on-making-mysql-scale/) .

Please describe your 'transactions'; there may be other techniques to improve performance.  For example, one `INSERT` with 100 rows runs about 10 times as fast as 100 single-row `INSERTs`; much of the savings in the CPU.